# The probability of drawing 7 red balls from an urn containing a total of 10 balls

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

The urn contains 10 balls, 3 of which are blue and 7 red. Two are arbitrarily drawn from the urn. The task is to calculate the probability of both balls being red. I know nothing about combinations and permutations, so my approach was to start by listing the balls:

$$B_1, B_2, B_3, R_1, R_2, R_3, R_4, R_5, R_6, R_7 \tag{Inventory}$$

We can represent that with the plain natural numbers (starting from 0 to simplify the table):

$$0, 1, \ldots, 9 \tag{Encoding}$$

The idea is that #5 is $R_1$, #1 is $B_2$ and so on. With 2 balls the space of outcomes is this:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
          & \color{blue}{\fbox{0}} & \color{blue}{\fbox{1}} & \color{blue}{\fbox{2}} & \color{red}{\fbox{3}} & \color{red}{\fbox{4}} & \color{red}{\fbox{5}} & \color{red}{\fbox{6}} & \color{red}{\fbox{7}} & \color{red}{\fbox{8}} & \color{red}{\fbox{9}}\\
        \color{blue}{\fbox{0}} & \color{blue}{00}&\color{blue}{01}&\color{blue}{02}& 03&04&05&06&07&08&09\\
        \color{blue}{\fbox{1}} & \color{blue}{10}&\color{blue}{11}&\color{blue}{12}& 13&14&15&16&17&18&19\\
        \color{blue}{\fbox{2}} & \color{blue}{20}&\color{blue}{21}&\color{blue}{22}& 23&24&25&26&27&28&29\\
        \color{red}{\fbox{3}} & 30& 31& 32& \color{red}{33}&\color{red}{34}&\color{red}{35}&\color{red}{36}&\color{red}{37}&\color{red}{38}&\color{red}{39}\\
        \color{red}{\fbox{4}} & 40& 41& 42& \color{red}{43}&\color{red}{44}&\color{red}{45}&\color{red}{46}&\color{red}{47}&\color{red}{48}&\color{red}{49}\\
        \color{red}{\fbox{5}} & 50& 51& 52& \color{red}{53}&\color{red}{54}&\color{red}{55}&\color{red}{56}&\color{red}{57}&\color{red}{58}&\color{red}{59}\\
        \color{red}{\fbox{6}} & 60& 61& 62& \color{red}{63}&\color{red}{64}&\color{red}{65}&\color{red}{66}&\color{red}{67}&\color{red}{68}&\color{red}{69}\\
        \color{red}{\fbox{7}} & 70& 71& 72& \color{red}{73}&\color{red}{74}&\color{red}{75}&\color{red}{76}&\color{red}{77}&\color{red}{78}&\color{red}{79}\\
        \color{red}{\fbox{8}} & 80& 81& 82& \color{red}{83}&\color{red}{84}&\color{red}{85}&\color{red}{86}&\color{red}{87}&\color{red}{88}&\color{red}{89}\\
        \color{red}{\fbox{9}} & 90& 91& 92& \color{red}{93}&\color{red}{94}&\color{red}{95}&\color{red}{96}&\color{red}{97}&\color{red}{98}&\color{red}{99}\\
        \end{matrix}
$$

For this particular problem we confine our attention to the bottom-right partition where both balls are red. There are $N(R) = 7\times 7 = 49$ such balls, and since there are $N(\Omega) = 10 \times 10 = 100$ possible events, the probability should be:

$$P(R) = {N(R) \over N(\Omega)} = {49 \over 100}. \tag{My Answer}$$

The book, however, calculates another number, using the formula $C_n^r = {n! \over r! \cdot (n-r)!}$:

$$C_{10}^2 = {10! \over 2! \cdot 8!} = 45,$$

$$C_{7}^2 = {7! \over 2! \cdot 5!} = 21,$$

$$P(R) = {C_{7}^2 \over C_{10}^2} = {7 \over 15}. \tag{The Answer}$$

I haven't studied permutations and combinations to any degree of satisfaction, so I don't get the intuition behind this approach. I don't doubt of course that $C_{10}^2$ is 45. I'm just not sure what that corresponds to on the table I've made. Maybe the table is completely useless? My questions are:

> **Question 1.** What's wrong with my approach? (Why am I getting 49 instead of 45?)
>
> **Question 2.** What's the intuition behind the use of the combinations formula here?

This second question may be too broad for this format, so please ignore it if that's the case. I'd appreciate any comments/answers to either of the questions.

Comment: Hint: You can't draw the same ball twice. Don't count the diagonal.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thank you so much! That makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint 1 : you can't draw the same ball twice.  Don't count the diagonal

Hint 2 : Symmetry.  Only you only need to count the proportion in the upper triangle.  The lower triangle has the same proportions.

$$
\begin{matrix}
& \color{blue}{\fbox{0}} & \color{blue}{\fbox{1}} & \color{blue}{\fbox{2}} & \color{red}{\fbox{3}} & \color{red}{\fbox{4}} & \color{red}{\fbox{5}} & \color{red}{\fbox{6}} & \color{red}{\fbox{7}} & \color{red}{\fbox{8}} & \color{red}{\fbox{9}}\\
\color{blue}{\fbox{0}} & ~&\color{blue}{01}&\color{blue}{02}& 03&04&05&06&07&08&09\\
 \color{blue}{\fbox{1}} & ~ &~&\color{blue}{12}& 13&14&15&16&17&18&19\\
\color{blue}{\fbox{2}} & ~&~&~& 23&24&25&26&27&28&29\\
\color{red}{\fbox{3}} & ~& ~& ~& ~&\color{red}{34}&\color{red}{35}&\color{red}{36}&\color{red}{37}&\color{red}{38}&\color{red}{39}\\
\color{red}{\fbox{4}} & ~& ~& ~& ~&~&\color{red}{45}&\color{red}{46}&\color{red}{47}&\color{red}{48}&\color{red}{49}\\
\color{red}{\fbox{5}} & ~& ~& ~& ~&~&~&\color{red}{56}&\color{red}{57}&\color{red}{58}&\color{red}{59}\\
\color{red}{\fbox{6}} & ~& ~& ~& ~&~&~&~&\color{red}{67}&\color{red}{68}&\color{red}{69}\\
\color{red}{\fbox{7}} & ~& ~& ~& ~&~&~&~&~&\color{red}{78}&\color{red}{79}\\
 \color{red}{\fbox{8}} & ~& ~& ~& ~&~&~&~&~&~&\color{red}{89}\\
\color{red}{\fbox{9}} & ~& ~& ~& ~&~&~&~&~&~&~\\
        \end{matrix}$$

---

For the combinations: There are $^7C_2$ ways to select 2 of the 7 red balls.  There are $^{10}C_2$ ways of picking 2 of all the balls.
$$\frac{^7C_2}{^{10}C_2}=\frac{7\times 6}{\color{gray}{2\times 1}} \frac{\color{gray}{2\times 1}}{10\times 9}$$

Which is the same as saying: there are 7 chances in 10 of picking one red ball, and after that 6 chances in 9 of picking another (from the remaining balls).

Comment: Thank you. Everything was immensely helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the probability of drawing one red ball is $7/10$. The probability of drawing a red ball from an urn with $9$ balls, $3$ of which are blue and $6$ of which are red is $6/9$. Thus, $$P(R)=\frac{7}{10}\cdot \frac{6}{9}$$ $$=\frac{7}{15}.$$

Comment: Using combinations are not necessary for problems like these.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing nothing about combinations or permutations, your approach is perfectly fine. However, you neglected the fact that it is impossible to draw the same ball twice. If you eliminate the entire diagonal and re-visit your method, you'll find that their are 42 ways to choose red balls, and 90 ways to choose balls in general. This will give you 42/90 = 7/15 as you desire.

Comment: Graham's earlier comment about this had already opened my eyes. But thanks for taking time to contribute!